# Работа с сессиями

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

Учусь работать с сессиями и мне надо их в базу данных как-то сохранять ( PostgreSQL ).  Пишу на nodejs с использованием Express.

```
app.use(
    session({
        secret:config.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave:true,
        saveUninitialized:true,
        cookie: {maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
        store:new pgSession({
            pg:pg,
            conString:"подключение к базе данных",
            tableName:"",
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 

        })
    })
    )
```

Так вот. Надо самому таблицу создавать в PostgreSQL или она автоматически создается как-то? Ибо смотрел  видео, там у мужика в mongoDB автоматически создалось... А здесь я попытался свою создать, так пишет то одной колонки не хватает, то другой.

Answer (score 0):

Никогда подключал PostgreeSQL к Node.js, но судя по описанию этот модуль может помочь вам. Покопайте его исходники, гляньте какие таблицы создаются [модуль подключения с инструкцией](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple)

И, как мне видиться, вот три поля которые должны быть в таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE "session" (
  "sid" varchar NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "sess" json NOT NULL,
    "expire" timestamp(6) NOT NULL
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "session" ADD CONSTRAINT "session_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("sid") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

Comment: А с какой БД вы работаете?

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка пропала, но записи не сохраняются :(

Comment: Я использую mongodb, вместе с надстройкой mongooze